"Application failed to respond" in Laravel deployment on Railway
I got this information when I tried to serve the Laravel project I hosted on railway.

Application failed to respond
This error appears to be caused by the application.
If this is your project, check out your deploy logs to see what went wrong. Refer to our docs on Fixing Common Errors for help, or reach out over our Help Station.
If you are a visitor, please contact the application owner or try again later.

I have gone to docs on fixing common errors and I don't understand what to do about it.
No idea of where to include the host and port talked about.
I'm so confused.

To fix this,
func main() {
  // ...
  // Use `PORT` provided in environment or default to 3000
  port := cmp.Or(os.Getenv("PORT"), 3000)

  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe((":" + port), handler))
  // ...
}

